# PostgreSQL rename table - cascade renaming to objects like indices, constraints that contain table name

Tags: postgresql

I renamed my tables with `ALTER TABLE _ RENAME TO _`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE foods RENAME TO food;
ALTER TABLE foods_nutrients RENAME TO food_nutrient;
```

It worked, however other database objects like indices, sequences and constraints that contained these table names didn't update. So I had to update them manually like this:

```sql
ALTER INDEX foods_pkey RENAME TO food_pkey;
ALTER SEQUENCE foods_id_seq RENAME TO food_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE food_nutrient RENAME CONSTRAINT foods_nutrients_food_id_fkey TO food_nutrient_food_id_fkey;
```

It wasn't necessary to rename them but it doesn't feel right to not do so. I wonder if there is command that does this automatically. Or is it not common to rename all objects containing the old table name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical relation between the names of indices, sequences, etc and any table names. So there is no reliable way to rename them automatically.

You can write a script that goes through the schema and renames things by search & replace, but that carries the risk of hitting false positives.